# What would have happened if Phil and Rita had stayed up?

Tags: groundhog-day

Every morning, Phil wakes up at 6:00AM, and finds the day completely reset. In an effort to woo Rita and prove his story, he convinces Rita to spend the night, who mistakenly believes that the day resets at midnight. The two end up falling asleep before the day resets, and Phil wakes up to find himself alone.

Had they not fallen asleep, would Rita have just disappeared at 6AM? Similarly, if Phil were to stay up until 6AM, would he magically just be transported back to bed? Does this scenario take place in any of the early scripts, or is it addressed anywhere?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This exchange from [Draft #2](http://www.dailyscript.com/scripts/groundhogday.pdf) of the script indicates that he's tried it (repeatedly).

In short, it doesn't work. He just wakes up at 6am.

> **PHIL:** ***I used to try to stay up all night sometimes***. I thought if I could stay conscious I could figure out what was going on, or at
>   least hang onto something from the day before. But **I gave up on that a
>   long time ago.**
>
> Rita looks at him with compassion.
>
> **RITA:** *It sounds so— lonely.*

Comment: It doesn't really say what happens to him, though. I guess he must wake up as if he'd been dreaming.

Comment: I think the implication is that when the clock strikes 6, he just wakes up in bed. It also explains why he didn't escape the town